# Eclipse's Ctrl+k equivalent in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code for my php projects. Coming from Eclipse I really miss `Ctrl+K` command which jumps to the next occurence of the same word and `Ctrl+Shift+K` goes to the previous. Is there an equivalent command in Visual Studio Code?

And also how to I go to the function definition in Visual Studio Code? 
In Eclipse it's press `Ctrl` and click.
In Sublime it's hover on function and click the subsequent path that appears.

I've done some research and installed PHP formatter extension. But that didn't give me anything.

Comment: You'll have more chance at https://superuser.com

Comment: I am able to right click and "Goto Definition" in Sublime, I *think* this is because I have the `PHP Companion` package installed.

Comment: There is an Eclipse keymap available https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings you could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the same key mapping as in eclipse for Visual Studio Code.

Here is the screenshot of vsc extension: "Eclipse Keymap"

[image]

Install it. Then By pressing

> Ctrl+K

will give the same functionality:

[image]

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Oh..Men, you are the champion.  Thanks for suggesting such an awesome plugin.